# Best way to architect an ajax-ready application

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using the MVC model with PHP. What's the best way to code an ajax-ready application?

To help you answer me I have a list of questions:

1. Should it be able to render content without javascript?
2. Should the main page consist only of a header and a footer and the content to be brought via ajax?
3. Should ajax bring directly html or json code? If json, it should be processed and rendered.
4. Any other idea?

UPDATE: Forget about search engines in this discussion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, it should be able to render HTML directly, at least for the first time a person lands on the page.
2. No, like I said, the main/first page should be loaded as HTML automatically, there's no need to load a page partially and then do an ajax request, it will just make it slower and the whole point of ajax is to make things faster.
3. This one really depends on what you need. If you're only loading content to be put into the layout then I would just load the HTML directly, but if you want to load variables that can be converted easily to objects for further manipulation than go with JSON.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes
2. You should include the content in the pages
3. Your choice

In order to allow search engines to index your site, all content must be available without Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you need is templates.
Any site that utilizes templates, already is ajax-ready.
To change a template call to json_encode is a matter of 1 line.

> Should the main page consist only of a header and a footer and the content to be brought via ajax?

Neither.
AJAX has a lot of disadvantages and should be used only for sensible reason. So, Most of your site will remain ajax-free.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would always strive for making the application work without javascript if it is possible to provide at least basic usability / information without Javascript. If that is the case, the way to go is [Progressive_enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement).

You seem to approach the issue the wrong way. Doing lots of requests of any kind usually is a bad thing, especially with AJAX requests. Browsers put very stingy limits on parallel resources and each request add latency. So generally, you want the least amount of AJAX or other resource requests possible.

Construct the base of your application in just HTML/CSS or javascript-only and then ask yourself where additional AJAX requests or other Javascript behavior are going to enhance your application the most.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents...

Start by getting the site to function correctly without JS and AJAX calls.
It will be better on the long term.

After that, gradually start AJAXifing things that will provide a better UX to your intended audience.

To get JSON only or HTML in your requests really depends on the content you are getting.

AJAX has its advantages and disadvantages, and every case need a different judgment on whether AJAX will provide a better UX on not.